# Java - custom integer division function

Tags: java, division, modulus, modular-arithmetic, modulo

I wrote a simple piece of code - `ceil1`. Since it failed my test cases after rewriting same code - `ceil` worked.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(ceil(3, 2)); //getting 2
    System.out.println(ceil1(3, 2)); //getting 1
}

public static int ceil(int dividend, int divisor){
    int a = dividend/divisor;
    int b = dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1;
    return a+b;
}

public static int ceil1(int dividend, int divisor){
    return dividend/divisor + dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1;
}}
```

I can't put my finger on what is difference between these two?
Possibly intermediate calculation/operator precedence causing this haywire.

Comment: Why not just `(a+b-1)/b`?

Comment: Try adding some brackets in ceil1

Comment: Yes, it's operator precedence causing your issue. Add brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
return dividend/divisor + dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1;
```

The addition of

```
dividend/divisor + dividend%divisor
```

is performed and then the result is compared to 0.

You want:

```
return dividend/divisor + (dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1);
```

or

```
return dividend/divisor + (dividend%divisor == 0) ? 0:1;
```

In order that only `dividend%divisor` will be compared to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The addition (`+`) operator has a higher precedence than the ternary (`?`) operator. You can surround that expression with parenthesis to get the behavior you want:

```
public static int ceil1(int dividend, int divisor){
    return dividend/divisor + (dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of `/`, `+`, `%` have a [higher precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `==`, hence

```
dividend/divisor + dividend%divisor == 0 ? 0:1
```

is equivalent to

```
(dividend/divisor + dividend%divisor) == 0 ? 0:1
```

So you will always get either 0 or 1 from this.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the precedence issue, your code produces incorrect answers.

For example, `ceil(-5, 3)` returns 0, whereas `Math,ceil(-5.0 / 3.0)` returns -1 (the "un-ceiled" value is `-1.666667`).

You will get the correct answer if you use a simpler approach:

```
(dividend + divisor - 1) / divisor
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3jhCji)

Comment: I was doing it only for positive integers. But this is awesome.

Comment: @AmitG if you're only doing it for positive integers, make sure you add precondition checks to your method so you fail with negative integers; it is far better to fail than to give the wrong answer.